# Cross Compile with Custome System Call and Header

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, arm, cross-compiling

I made a new system call to arm linux kernel, which also have a custom header in include/linux.

In cross compile, how to call the new system call? And how to include the header?

Because the call and the header is of course not on the host system, I receive header not found and implicit reference to system call.

EDIT: This is school-related, so I have to stick with new system call.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to specify -I option to the compiler to specifiy header directory with modified files? Did you consider to use other interface to access kernel - dev or sys - rather to implement new system call? It is much easier to work with them. It depends on functionality you want from kernel.

Comment: I'm curious to know why you're implementing a system call in the first place. 99.999% of the time, creating a new system call is the wrong way to do whatever you want to achieve.

Comment: Refer "man gettid" for simple way. Updating headers and glibc not easy.